# Android textView size is bigger than dynamically created one

Tags: android, textview, size

I got some issue with dynamically created TextViews. To be more specific:

```
                    <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Some text"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="30px" />
```

appears much larger than:

```
            TextView prName = new TextView(this);
            prName.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
            prName.setText("Some text");
            prName.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 30);
```

How to made them equal? Thanks beforehand

Comment: @ Rasulbek Abdurasulov : In android use only sp for defining textsize. Please read : http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For text you should use scale points (SP) instead of pixel.

For xml:

```
 android:textSize="30sp"
```

For code:

```
 prName.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 30);
```

Comment: Yeah, you should use sp instead of px for TextView.

Answer (score 1):

Set height and width as wrap_content for your textview.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams Params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
prName.setLayoutParams(Params1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure when you setTextSize for any type of view, you should set it in scalable points (sp) and not in pixels (px) like this:

**In xml:**

```
android:textSize="18sp"
```

**In code:**

```
prName.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);
```

Using scalable points will let your TextView text size be equal on all devices, while using pixels will let your TextView text size be unequal on devices with different resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

```
prName.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 30);
```

... or use this instead:

```
prName.setTextSize(30);
```

Comment: I wanted to make it 30 pixel-size textView not 30dp. In your case it is 30 dp.

Answer (score 0):

use **`setTextSize(int unit, float size)`**

```
TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX   //Pixels

TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP   //Scaled Pixels

TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP  //Device Independent Pixels
```

In here just set

```
prName.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);
```